# Error using zlib on ios

Tags: ios, zlib

This is the code I use to read from a compressed resource file and write the decompressed data to a file in the documents directory:

```
- (void)setupPFile
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
        NSString* documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString* passwordsFile = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"p.txt"];
        BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:passwordsFile];

        if (!fileExists) {
            NSString *resourceDictPass = DICTIONARY_FILE;
            NSString *resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:resourceDictPass ofType:@"gz"];
            NSData *fileCompressedData= [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:resourcePath];
            NSError *error = nil;
            [fileCompressedData writeInflatedToFile:passwordsFile error:&error];
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"error uncompressing passwords file");
                return;
            }
        }

    });
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
Printing description of error:
Error Domain=se.bitba.ZlibErrorDomain Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (se.bitba.ZlibErrorDomain error 2.)"
```

I am using a NSData+zlib category I found recommended around here.
How to debug this?

Comment: Look at the source and see where that error is generated.

Comment: In writeInflatedToFile

Comment: So, figure out what's going on, and why the error is being raised.

Comment: How do I downvote you?

Comment: About 95% of programming is "figuring out what's going on".  If you don't feel you're capable of doing that you should find another occupation.

Comment: Guess SO should be closed then.